# Hurry up and answer

Tags: riddle, word

In one sense, I might describe a room,
Or part of a play, originally French.

In another, I'm used for comparison,
Perhaps to improve by a factor.

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,
If you've got me down to a tee.

What am I? Identify me.

---

Hint:

> Each of the three stanzas of the riddle refers to a slightly different word, but all three are closely related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In one sense, I might describe a room, Or part of a play, originally French.

> A **waiting** room, or Waiting for Godot - originally published in French as En attendant Godot.

In another, I'm used for comparison, Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> **weighting** - weights on a scale or assigning values which may improve a rating.

Almost, I'm a tag on this site, If you've got me down to a tee.

> [weighing](/questions/tagged/weighing) is a PSE tag and is just a 't' off.

Title: Hurry up and answer

> You're waiting for the answer.

Comment: This must be right.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Line 4 specifically refers to using these things as factors to improve averages. (@Gareth did I live up to your expectations of this answer fitting better than yours or others?)

Comment: Fantastic. Fits all clues so well.  I am surprised though that there are so many other answers that are close. Good question great answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, I agree (unsurprisingly) that this is more convincing than my attempt :-).

Comment: Congrats on 60k reputation, @Tom!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are

> DOUBLE.

In one sense, I might describe a room,
Or part of a play, originally French.

> A double room in a hotel is one that sleeps two. If "play" can mean "playing a game" then there are lots of games in which something is called "double". The word "double" in English comes to us via French (in all its senses, I think).

In another, I'm used for comparison,
Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> One thing is double another if it's twice as big.

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,
If you've got me down to a tee.

> There is a [word-ladder] tag. Lewis Carroll called word-ladders "doublets". (The idea was that "if you've got me down to a tee" means to add a T to the word, of course. OP's comments below indicate that this is not in fact the correct answer, though that still might be part of how this couplet operates.)

Title:

> On, or at, the double.

Comment: The "play" probably refers to rot13(qbhoyr ragraqer, n cynl ba jbeqf)

Comment: I'm surprised to see who answered this, since you're normally spot-on. It's not bad, but some of these explanations (especially lines 2 and 5-6) are a bit of a stretch. I hope that, when the intended solution is found, you'll agree that it fits all the clues in a more natural way :-)

Comment: I, correspondingly, was a little surprised that so much stretching seemed required :-). I'm glad to hear there's something better to be found.

Comment: (Though lines 5-6 weren't the part that seemed most of a stretch to me, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Suite

In one sense, I might describe a room,

> A [suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_(hotel)) is a type of hotel room.

Or part of a play, originally French.

> A [suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_(music)) is an ordered set of orchestral pieces which developed, originally, in 17th century France.

In another, I'm used for comparison,

> I think this refers to a [geological suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_(geology)) which is a collection of rock specimens from a given area or a succession of closely associated sedimentary strata and consists of two or more lithodemes of a single genetic class.

Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> I think this refers to a [software suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_suite) which often improves computation by a significant factor over using disparate programs.

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,

> It could be "pur**suit-e**vasion" which is a tag on this site.

If you've got me down to a tee.

> Not sure about this line, possibly refers to shortening "suite" to "suit" (down to a "t") which may relate to the [cards](/questions/tagged/cards) tag.

Title

> "tout suite" means "right now" in French.

Comment: In your last spoiler block you're missing a "de".

Comment: This is probably right.

Comment: I'm guessing not (though it's ingenious, for sure) -- I think lines 4 and 5-6 don't fit well enough. But we'll see...

Comment: Nice try, especially for lines 1-2, but the rest of it is more of a stretch. There is a reason for the division of the riddle into separate verses.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Premier, premiere, premium, and prime.

In one sense, I might describe a room,

> Premier rooms in a hotel.

Or part of a play, originally French.

> Premiere, the first performance of a play.

In another, I'm used for comparison,
Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> Premium: "of exceptional quality."

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,
If you've got me down to a tee.

> “prime” is a truncated, albeit rearranged, version of “premium”, and a tag on PSE.

Comment: You get a +1 for another answer which *almost* fits, but again the explanation for lines 3-4 is a bit vague (the intended meaning has a more specific connection with those lines), and nothing for line 6 here.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> Ante/Anti

*In one sense, I might describe a room*,

> Antechamber

*Or part of a play, originally French.*

> In poker part of a play (a hand of poker) is to set the ante

*In another, I'm used for comparison,*

> Anti - the opposite of something. Used to compare

*Perhaps to improve by a factor.*

> This is where I start to think I'm going down the wrong path

*Almost, I'm a tag on this site,*

> I'll keep scrolling through the tags to see if one fits...

*If you've got me down to a tee.*

> anti/ante/antee down to 'A tee' - not sure here, everything seems like a stretch

Comment: Wow, for the first few lines you had me convinced this fits so well that my riddle must be too broad ... then it kind of petered out :-P Good try, but not the answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I was convinced too! Thats why I started, thought it fit so well it had to be right...and then...yeah...the rest didn't fit

Answer (score 2):

You are a:

> STAGE

In one sense, I might describe a room,

> A STAGE as the freedictionary.com describes it: A resting place on a journey, especially one providing overnight accommodations. This might describe a room.

Or part of a play, originally French.

> STAGE are where performers of a play perform and it comes from the Old French word ESTAGE.

In another, I'm used for comparison,
Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> The word can also mean a LEVEL and one can use levels as a way to compare things in their superiority or inferiority in relation to one another. The 'next stage' in this sense of the word means an improvement.

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,
If you've got me down to a tee.

> STAGE- S is TAGE (to reach a T) which is almost TAG.

Title:

> The title could be implying: Hurry up the stages of the solving process and give an answer!

Also:

> The riddle is layed out in 3 distinct stages.

Comment: Sorry, nope, but +1 for a good try which fits some parts well. As I mentioned on another answer, for the last verse it's not just TAG as a word but specifically a tag on this site. Also lines 3-4 have a ... more specific meaning than this.

Answer (score 1):

What am I? Identify me.

> log

In one sense, I might describe a room,

> Middle English `loge`, via Old French loge meaning `arbor` or `hut`

Or part of a play, originally French.

> In French theatre, the green room/dressing room is called `les loges`

In another, I'm used for comparison,

> we use logarithms to compare, eg earthquakes with the Richter scale, acidity with the pH scale

Perhaps to improve by a factor.

> logarithms are the inverse of exponential functions, and both can be used to increase a number by a factor

Almost, I'm a tag on this site,

> `log` is not a tag but several tags exist that start with `log...`

If you've got me down to a tee.

> shell scripting often uses a final `tee` program which additionally `logs` to the screen, allowing operators to verify every stage is completed correctly down to a tee

Comment: I gotta say I *like* this one :-) but sadly not correct. The tag/tee part feels like a bit of a stretch, and I don't know anything about programming. I think I'll edit the question to add a hint.